# Beautiful Soup to Download PDFs from Multiple Pages

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

[Andrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) kindly helped me write this code, but now I'm wondering how to navigate to each of those pages and download all the PDFs that have the text/title "Public Comment" in the name?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?AMID=41"
key = "Archive.aspx?ADID="

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if key in link.get("href", ""):
        print("https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/" + link.get("href"))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3581
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3570
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3564
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3559
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3556
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3554
https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3552
```

Comment: Where should be the string "Public Comments" located? Can you give example URL?

Comment: If you click on: https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3552 there is a link (https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/DocumentCenter/View/8928/Public-Comments_4282021) that takes you to a PDF I need to download and parse for email addresses/names.

Comment: Better example: https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3461 > https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/DocumentCenter/View/8399/Public-Comment_Leaf-Blower_11182020_Rev4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?AMID=41"
key = "Archive.aspx?ADID="

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_links = []
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if key in link.get("href", ""):
        all_links.append("https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/" + link.get("href"))

for link in all_links:
    print("Checking {}...".format(link))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    for a in soup.find_all(
        lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and "public comment" in tag.text.lower()
    ):
        pdf_link = "https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us" + a["href"]
        filename = a["href"].split("/")[-1] + ".pdf"
        print("Downloading {} to {}".format(pdf_link, filename))
        with open(filename, "wb") as f_out:
            f_out.write(requests.get(pdf_link).content)
```

Prints:

```
...

Checking https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3514...
Checking https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3505...
Downloading https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/DocumentCenter/View/8628/Public-Comments-1202021---ITEM-No-15 to Public-Comments-1202021---ITEM-No-15.pdf
Checking https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3498...
Checking https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/Archive.aspx?ADID=3479...
Downloading https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/DocumentCenter/View/8516/Wayne-Lee---Public-Comments_12162020 to Wayne-Lee---Public-Comments_12162020.pdf
Downloading https://www.ci.atherton.ca.us/DocumentCenter/View/8532/Discher-Stephanie_Public-Comments_12162020 to Discher-Stephanie_Public-Comments_12162020.pdf

...
```

And saves the PDFs from the URL to files.